# How to use nested loop in terraform

Tags: azure, terraform

I am trying to create 3 VM's in Azure using Terraform count and each VM requires multiple disks. Is there any way to accomplish this ? I tried creating map of disk name and sizes but got an error that I can not use count and for_each together?

```
resource "azurerm_managed_disk" "this" {
  for_each             = var.disks
  count                = each.value > 0 ? var.node_count : 0
  name                 = format("%s-%02d-datadisk", each.key, count.index + 1)
  location             = var.location
  resource_group_name  = var.resource_group_name
  storage_account_type = "Premium_LRS"
  create_option        = "Empty"
  disk_size_gb         = each.value

  tags = {
    environment = "staging"
  }
 }  

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_data_disk_attachment" "this" {
  for_each           = var.disks
  count              = each.value > 0 ? var.node_count : 0
  managed_disk_id    = azurerm_managed_disk.this.*.id[count.index]
  virtual_machine_id = azurerm_virtual_machine.this.*.id[count.index]
  lun                = "10"
  caching            = "None"
}

vm.tf
variable "disks" {
  description = "Map of disk name and respective disk size"
  type        = map(string)
  default     = {
    "binlog_disk"    = "30"
    "innodb_disk"    = "20"
    "data_disk"      = "100"
    "tmp_disk"       = "10"
    "backup_disk"    = "150"
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not just use `for_each` in `azurerm_virtual_machine_data_disk_attachment` too?

Comment: I missed that but error remains the same.

Comment: It would replace `count`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key requirement for [resource `for_each`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#for_each-multiple-resource-instances-defined-by-a-map-or-set-of-strings) is that you construct a map that has one element for each instance you want to create.

In this case, you want one instance for each (instance, disk) pair, which is a good use-case for [the `setproduct` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/setproduct.html). In this case, because one of your resources is using `count`, we'll combine it with [the `range` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/range.html) to produce a suitable sequence of integers to identify the instances:

```
locals {
  instance_disks = {
    for pair in setproduct(range(length(azurerm_virtual_machine.this)), keys(var.disks)) : "${pair[0]}:${pair[1]}" => {
      vm_index  = pair[0]
      disk_key  = pair[1]
      disk_size = var.disks[pair[1]]
    }
  }
}
```

The above will produce a map with one element per pair of virtual machine index and disk, with elements like this:

```
{
  "0:binlog_disk" = {
    vm_index  = 0
    disk_key  = "binlog_disk"
    disk_size = 30
  },
  "1:binlog_disk" = {
    vm_index  = 1
    disk_key  = "binlog_disk"
    disk_size = 30
  },
  etc...
}
```

This map meets the resource `for_each` requirement, so we can use it as the `for_each` expression in the `azurerm_managed_disk` and `azurerm_virtual_machine_data_disk_attachment` resources:

```
resource "azurerm_managed_disk" "this" {
  for_each = local.instance_disks

  name                 = format("%s-%02d-datadisk", each.value.disk_key, each.value.instance_index + 1)
  location             = var.location
  resource_group_name  = var.resource_group_name
  storage_account_type = "Premium_LRS"
  create_option        = "Empty"
  disk_size_gb         = each.value.disk_size

  tags = {
    environment = "staging"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_data_disk_attachment" "this" {
  for_each = local.instance_disks

  managed_disk_id    = azurerm_managed_disk.this[each.key].id
  virtual_machine_id = azurerm_virtual_machine.this[each.value.instance_index].id
  lun                = "10"
  caching            = "None"
}
```

The addresses of the instances of these resources will use the same keys as the map, giving addresses like this:

- `azurerm_managed_disk.this["0:binlog_disk"]`
- `azurerm_managed_disk.this["1:binlog_disk"]`
- ...
- `azurerm_managed_disk.this["0:innodb_disk"]`
- `azurerm_managed_disk.this["1:innodb_disk"]`
- ...

It's important to think about the instance keys you're using for a resource because they decide how Terraform will understand changes to the underlying map. In this case in particular, because we're identifying the virtual machines by their positions in the `count` sequence, reducing the number of virtual machines by one would be understood by Terraform as a request to destroy all of the attachments which have the highest index. Removing the `innodb_disk` entry from `var.disks` would be understood by Terraform as a request to destroy all of the attachments whose addresses end with `:innodb_disk`.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with [`v0.12`](http://ttps://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-vsphere/issues/415) and above. You can do something like this,

```
variable "disks" {
  default = [
    {
      unit_number = 0
      size = "80"
      thin_provisioned = true
    },
  ]
}

  dynamic "disk" {
    for_each = [for s in var.disks: {
      label = s.unit_number == "0" ? "${var.name}.vmdk" : "${var.name}_${s.unit_number}.vmdk"
      unit_number = s.unit_number
      size = s.size
      thin_provisioned = contains(keys(s),"thin_provisioned") ? s.thin_provisioned : "true"
    }]
    content {
      label = disk.value.label
      unit_number = disk.value.unit_number
      size = disk.value.size
      thin_provisioned = disk.value.thin_provisioned
    }
  }
```

Comment: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#when-to-use-for_each-instead-of-count