# Looping over list of list

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have an `aws_route` resource where I want to update all routing tables from list with new routes. Here is the relevant code:

```
resource "aws_route" "private_route" {
  for_each = data.aws_route_tables.private_route_tables.ids

  route_table_id          = each.key
  destination_cidr_block  = var.tgw_destination_cidr_block
  transit_gateway_id      = module.tgw.ec2_transit_gateway_id
}
```

Above code works fine when there is one CIDR defined in variable `tgw_destination_cidr_block`, as `aws_route` requires string type for `destination_cidr_block` attribute.

```
tgw_destination_cidr_block = "10.255.160.0/20"
```

Now I want to add multiple CIDR ranges in this variable, and to iterate through it.

```
tgw_destination_cidr_block = ["10.255.160.0/20", "10.255.176.0/22"]
```

in order to create two new routes in each routing table. So, I guess I need list of string in the variable and to iterate through list of CIDR ranges.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: You need a nested loop over both the route tables and the CIDRs so this needs you to first create a product of those two lists/sets with [`setproduct`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/setproduct.html). https://stackoverflow.com/a/62565413/2291321 gives a good example of how to do that.

Comment: If the above linked answer solves your problem then that's great and we can close this as a duplicate to improve how people can find that answer. If not, could you please edit your question to show what you tried from that answer that didn't work for you instead so that people can help narrow down any issues with it?

Comment: Thank you @ydaetskcoR . I used the solution provided below, as it's refer to my use case. But the one from link you posted is very close to this as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When thinking about `for_each` expressions I always start by thinking through what might end the sentence "declare one instance for each of ...", and in this case it seems like that sentence would be:

> Declare one instance for each pair of private route table and destination CIDR block.

This tells us then that we need a collection where each element represents one of those pairs.

The usual way to find all of the combinations of multiple sets of items is [the `setproduct` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/setproduct.html), and its documentation has a section [Finding combinations for `for_each`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/setproduct.html#finding-combinations-for-for_each) that shows a worked example of declaring a systematic set of subnets for a number of different base networks.

We can adapt that example to your problem as follows. The example in the docs already works it through in small steps, so I'm going to merge all of the local value expressions into a single one here for simplicity's sake:

```
locals {
  route_table_routes = [
    for pair in setproduct(data.aws_route_tables.private_route_tables.ids, var.tgw_destination_cidr_blocks) : {
      route_table_id         = pair[0]
      destination_cidr_block = pair[1]
    }
  ]
}

resource "aws_route" "private_route" {
  for_each = {
    for rtr in local.route_table_routes : "${rtr.route_table_id}:${rtr.destination_cidr_block}" => rtr
  }

  route_table_id          = each.value.route_table_id
  destination_cidr_block  = each.value.destination_cidr_block
  transit_gateway_id      = module.tgw.ec2_transit_gateway_id
}
```

The above will declare `aws_route.private_route` instances whose keys are a combination of route table ID and destination CIDR block.

Note that it can be problematic to use ids assigned by the remote system as part of your instance keys in Terraform, because Terraform needs those instance keys to be fully known throughout the whole plan and apply process. However, in your case you are retrieving those route table ids using a data source and so they will be known during planning as long as your data resource configuration itself can be fully known during planning.

Usually I'd recommend having the same configuration be responsible for declaring both the route tables and these routes, and thus be able to give each of the route tables a static key known entirely from configuration (not decided by the remote system at all), but that sort of design isn't always practical in a decomposed system, and so what you're doing here can be okay as long as you take care to ensure that you apply changes to your separate Terraform configurations in the correct order so that the changes will cascade in the way you're intending, even though Terraform can't see the whole dependency structure and therefore can't guarantee the ordering itself.

Comment: This is a good answer but I think the other linked answer (also yours!) in my comment might be a better one (albeit in a generic sense as it doesn't use these specific resources) so think it might be better to close it as a duplicate instead and try to have a more canonical target for these types of questions.

Comment: I've also considered where we have some types of questions that come up regularly whether we should create a complete, generic Q&A combo (like happens on some more trafficked tags) that solves that in a nice generic way but haven't had the time to look at that and didn't want to do it unilaterally back when I was the only gold tag badge holder. There's probably a good argument that this is premature optimisation though considering the relatively low amount of questions on the tag.

Comment: Thank you @Martin for such detailed explanation and solution which is actually what is written in terraform docs you shared for this kind of tasks. Also really appreciate solution for my use case entirely.

Comment: Martin wrote those docs as well so :)